# Using grep -f but it only returns results that match the last pattern in my list

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file with a list of patterns (pattern.txt). I have a file I want to search and extract the lines from that match any of my list of patterns (search.txt). I then write to a new file (output.txt)

pattern.txt

```
Scaffold1\>
Scaffold4\>
```

search.txt

```
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold2   401
Scaffold4   123
Scaffold11  452
```

Output I would like is

```
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold4   123
```

Output I get is:

```
Scaffold4   123
```

The code I am using is:

```
grep -f pattern.txt search.txt > output.txt
```

This works but only outputs results for the last pattern in my pattern.txt file.

I am using GNU Grep 2.5.3.

I have found other questions that suggest using the -f function for grep to search for multiple patterns in this way so I think it should work, none have the problem I am having. I have checked my file for empty lines and tried combining with e.g. -E or -F but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Was your `pattern.txt` file generated on Windows? If so, it may contain `\r` characters (carriage returns) at the end of each line. If it contains NO line ending character on the last line, then that would be the only one that `grep` gets that will match correctly.

Comment: It works for me. My money is on ghoti's suspicion.

Comment: @ghoti yes you're right.

Comment: It works for me, agree with @ghoti suspicion, double check your `pattern.txt` file.

Comment: YAY! It works, thank you @ghoti for your helpful comments, I had a suspicion it would be something annoyingly simple like this! Always learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution to your problem works fine for me:

```
➜  test cat pattern.txt
Scaffold1\>
Scaffold4\>
➜  test cat search.txt
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold2   401
Scaffold4   123
Scaffold11  452
➜  test grep -f pattern.txt search.txt
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold1   301
Scaffold4   123
➜  test
```

The issue you are facing is most likely to do with the way that new lines are handled. If your file created in windows, the carriage return characters will not be in a format that unix tools will understand.

To fix this, you can convert the file using a tool called `dos2unix` or some bash magic with common string manipulation tools such as `awk`. There is a good article [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux) describing a few different methods, but my favourite is simply this:

```
➜  dos2unix search.txt > search_unix.txt
dos2unix: converting file search.txt to Unix format ...
➜
```